# how can I add a comment to a jira issue after hudson perform the build?

Tags: eclipse, svn, hudson, jira, jql

I'm trying to create a job in hudson that add a comment to a JIRA task based on the last commit.

I'm doing commits from eclipse/svn with the following structure

```
PROJECT-NAME: Title of the project

Task Url: http://.....
```

The JIRA plugin from eclipse auto generate that comment.

Now, in hudson, on my job configuration, on the build section I'm adding a "Progress JIRA issues by workflow action". What I need to do here is to add a JQL that get me the task associated to my last commit so I can add a comment only to that task.

I don't know if JQL can do that.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: Q: Which Jenkins/Hudon plugin are you using?

Comment: Q: How does the task url look like `https://jira-server/browse/<project-id>-<issue-number>` ?

Comment: yes it looks like thatr

Comment: Q: Which Jenkins/Hudon plugin are you using?

Comment: I'm using this http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/JIRA+Plugin